# Two Local Notifications Error

Tags: uilocalnotification

I am making an application which uses local notifications. I am trying it out and am using two instances. When I run kill the app, only one notification shows up. This is the code in the app delegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{


//1
NSCalendar *gregcalendar2 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *datecomponent2 = [gregcalendar2 components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[datecomponent2 setYear:2013];
[datecomponent2 setMonth:6];
[datecomponent2 setDay:18];
[datecomponent2 setHour:16];
[datecomponent2 setMinute:58];

UIDatePicker *dd2 = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[dd2 setDate:[gregcalendar2 dateFromComponents:datecomponent2]];


UILocalNotification *notification2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification2 setAlertBody:@"two"];
[notification2 setFireDate:dd2.date];
[notification2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification2]];


//2

NSCalendar *gregcalendar1 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *datecomponent1 = [gregcalendar1 components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[datecomponent1 setYear:2013];
[datecomponent1 setMonth:6];
[datecomponent1 setDay:18];
[datecomponent1 setHour:16];
[datecomponent1 setMinute:59];

UIDatePicker *dd1 = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[dd1 setDate:[gregcalendar1 dateFromComponents:datecomponent1]];


UILocalNotification *notification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification1 setAlertBody:@"one"];
[notification1 setFireDate:dd1.date];
[notification1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification1]];
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do:

```
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification2]];
```

and then

```
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification1]];
```

which means: replace ALL previously scheduled local notifications (in this case, notification2) with array containing `notification1`.

Instead of this, you can use:

```
[application scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];
[application scheduleLocalNotification:notification2];
```

or:

```
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:@[notification1, notification2]];
```